# Does transmission gratings have their max efficiency always at some finite incident angle $\ne0$

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, interference, diffraction

Let say we are interested only in transmission gratings. The Bragg condition is $\theta_{incident}=asin(\lambda_L/2\Lambda)$ .

Does the incident angle onto the grating change the maximum diffracted efficiency into some order ?

Can you have optimized grating at normal incidence angle ?

Answer (score 1):

For a symmetric grating, at normal incidence you will always have diffraction in to equivalent orders on both sides of normal (e.g. both +1 and -1 orders), and they will be equal by symmetry. A blazed grating will favor one over the other, but as long as one is allowed, the other will be allowed as well.

Off normal, you may be able to make the -1 order disallowed (although that may enable the +2 order). Blazing appropriately will only increase the imbalance further.

So, yes, in general going off-normal will enhance one order.